# 'silent_install.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: flutter, android-studio, haxm

I'm trying to download HAXM for android studio, but every time the installation stops halfway and shows the error

> 'silent_install.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Install the newest haxm (HAXM v7.7.0 at github.com/intel/haxm/releases). If any issues will occur during installation, HAXM installer will show a detailed output of what exactly failed.

Comment: @Ramish Did it get resolved for you? I am facing the same issue